# main.tsx:1 Failed to load module script

Tags: vite, github-pages, react-typescript

Having the issue:

main.tsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I am using Github Pages, using vite, react, typescript. Public repo can be found in https://github.com/berkeleybrasa/brasa-site. My navbar doesn't show up.

I tried changing package.json and the config file but didn't work.